# suggestion for java design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

i'm starting using design pattern  in java .now i'm writing a java code that pass all  this tests :

```
@Test
    public void createOrder() {
        final Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
        final int tableId = restaurant.initTable(4);
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Joe: Soup");
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Jim: Same");
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Jack: Chips");
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "John: Chips");
        assertEquals("Soup, Soup, Chips, Chips",
                restaurant.createOrder(tableId));
    }

    @Test
    public void failedCreationBecauseNotEveryoneOrdered() {
        final Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
        final int tableId = restaurant.initTable(4);
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Joe: Soup");
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Joe: Spaghetti");
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Jim: Roastbeef");
        assertEquals("MISSING 2", restaurant.createOrder(tableId));
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Jack: Spaghetti");
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "John: Chips");
        assertEquals("Spaghetti, Roastbeef, Spaghetti, Chips",
                restaurant.createOrder(tableId));
    }

    @Test
    public void failedCreationBecauseNotEnoughPeopleForADishFor2() {

        final Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
        final int tableId = restaurant.initTable(4);
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Joe: Soup");
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Jim: Same");
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Joe: Fish for 2");
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "Jack: Chips");
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "John: Chips");
        assertEquals("MISSING 1 for Fish for 2",
                restaurant.createOrder(tableId));
        restaurant.customerSays(tableId, "John: Fish for 2");
        assertEquals("Fish for 2, Soup, Chips, Fish for 2",
                restaurant.createOrder(tableId));
    }
```

i'm starting using the Factory design pattern :

[mydesign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mffaw.png)
 but i think its not the correct one to use ! any suggestion ?

Comment: where are you using the factory design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see here a chance for three patterns:

- The *facade* pattern to model the `Restaurant` class: It seems that `Restaurant` should contain its own model and sub-patterns, and that it merely exposes all the methods needed to access them.
- The *command* pattern to implement the `customerSays` method: Most likely, it should privately create an object to model the requested operation.
- The *parser* pattern (oh, OK: I don't know if it might be considered a pattern, but still a parser is needed here): This one will take the string argument of `customerSays`, analyze it char by char, and produce a specific javabean with specific properties.

Anyway, you will see it more clear if you start by designing the model of objects and relationships in the most rational way to accomplish the given tests, without paying much attention to the exact method signatures. Then, when you finally got it, design the `Restaurant` class to group them together, now taking in account the requested method signatures.